# Change table row value text color if values are the same

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have this table and i need the values "Age" and "ID" text to be red if the values are the same.

Index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="table"></div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
tableData = [
  { id: 23, date: "01/01/1999", age: "23" },
  { id: 21, date: "01/01/1877", age: "24" },
  { id: 24, date: "01/01/1748", age: "25" },
  { id: 26, date: "01/01/1458", age: "26" },
  { id: 20, date: "01/01/1354", age: "27" },
  { id: 1, date: "01/01/1225", age: "28" },
];

const homeDiv = document.getElementById("table");
tbl = document.createElement("table");

const tr1 = tbl.insertRow();
const td1 = tr1.insertCell();
td1.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #212529; color: white; padding: 8px; border: 2px solid #212529");
td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Random Table"));
const tr2 = tbl.insertRow();
const td2 = tr2.insertCell();

for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(tableData).length; i++) {
  const tr1 = tbl.insertRow();
  const td1 = tr1.insertCell();
  td1.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #212529; color: white; padding: 8px; border: 2px solid #212529");
  td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Date: ${tableData[i]["date"]}`));

  const tr2 = tbl.insertRow();
  const td2 = tr2.insertCell();
  td2.setAttribute("style", "border: 2px solid #212529; font-size: 14px;");
  td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Age: "));
  td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tableData[i]["age"]));

  const tr3 = tbl.insertRow();
  const td3 = tr3.insertCell();
  td3.setAttribute("style", "border: 2px solid #212529; font-size: 14px");
  td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ID: "));
  td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tableData[i]["id"]));
}

homeDiv.appendChild(tbl);
```

This is how it looks right now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRgG7.png

This is more or less what i want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTmMy.png

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, define a variable `color` and set it to `black`/`red` depending on the condition `id == age`:

```
[...]
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(tableData).length; i++) {
  const tr1 = tbl.insertRow();
  const td1 = tr1.insertCell();
  td1.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #212529; color: white; padding: 8px; border: 2px solid #212529");
  td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Date: ${tableData[i]["date"]}`));
  // default to black
  var color = "black";
  // if id and age are the same, use red
  if (("" + tableData[i]["id"]) == tableData[i]["age"]) {
    color = "red";
  }
  const tr2 = tbl.insertRow();
  const td2 = tr2.insertCell();
  // use chosen color
  td2.setAttribute("style", "border: 2px solid #212529; font-size: 14px; color: " + color + ";");
  td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Age: "));
  td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tableData[i]["age"]));

  const tr3 = tbl.insertRow();
  const td3 = tr3.insertCell();
  // use chosen color
  td3.setAttribute("style", "border: 2px solid #212529; font-size: 14px; color: " + color + ";");
  td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ID: "));
  td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tableData[i]["id"]));
}
[...]
```